# Accessing a particular instance of class inside the same class in java

Tags: java, class, pointers, singleton

I have a java code with the structure that is shown below:

```
public class x{   
                public static void main(string[] args)
                {
                    ysample1 = new y(m)
                    ysample2 = new y(l)
                           ....

                }
              }

   public class y{ 
                private int m_m
                public y(int  m) 
                {
                    m_m = m
                }
               public void control()
               {

                     h h1 = new h(ysample2)
               }
          }
```

At some point when I want to call method control for ysample1 I may need to access ysample2 object.How can I define instance of class y global, so I can access ysample2 inside the control method in class y?

Does anyone know how can I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Add a parameter to `control`: `public void control(y target)`. You can then call `ysample1.control(ysample2);` in your main method, after changing `h h1 = new h1(ysample2)` to `h h1 = new h1(target)`

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I will look at it again to see if I can do it like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do the way you wrote it.

I think you need to ridefine "control()" method like this:

```
               public void control(Y ysample)
           {

                 h h1 = new h(ysample)
           }
```

So now you need to have an "ysample" as parameter and you can do from your main

```
control(ysample2);
```

and you will have what i understood from you question. If you need something else please comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look at it  see if I can use this idea to fix my problem.